# Python input() function doesn't accept input after focus is returned to Terminal

Tags: python, macos, input, terminal

My Python code below will sometimes stop accepting keyboard input if I change Terminal window focus. (It's paused on "Press [Enter] Key to start distribution...") but when I press enter it doesn't do anything...just hangs and I have to restart the program. There's other tasks I need to complete in the background before pressing the return key to continue running the script so it's impossible to keep window focus on Terminal. If I restart the script then it works fine again. **How can I fix this?** I asked AI and it says, "It's essential to ensure that you have the focus on the Terminal window when the input() function is expecting input to avoid any unintended consequences." (I do things like I go to Parallels, open Word documents, read email...etc.)

```
while True:
    try: 
        # Prompt for user input
        input("Press [Enter] key to start distribution...").strip()

        # Check to see there's 10 MP2 Files. 
        mp2_files = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Amboss/*.MP2"))
        destination_folder = os.path.join(myPath, f"TTB/TTB_Finals_Weekly/TTB_{dir_week}/Amboss_Distribution[7]/".format(dir_week))
        
        # Copy all files first. This ensures you have all files in appropriate directory before uploading.
        for file in mp2_files:
            shutil.copy(file, destination_folder)

        escaped_folder_path = glob.escape(destination_folder) # There's [] in filename so you gotta escape those. 
        number_of_MP2_files = len(glob.glob(os.path.join(escaped_folder_path, "*.MP2")))

        if number_of_MP2_files != 8:
            raise ValueError("Number of MP2 files does not equal 8, please check MP2 files.")

        break  
        
    except ValueError as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
```

Comment: Python doesn't know anything about window focus, thay's handled entirely by the terminal emulator. Are you sure you brought focus back to the terminal window with python in it?

Comment: I've never run into this before., This doesn't sound like a Python question though. Are you using some weird terminal?

Comment: Same here, have never run into this. But in your case you may try some different approaches rather than bare `input()` which is buggy at times. Something like [signals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) and starting a distribution, this might help with hanging.

Comment: @DiMithras This is the first I've heard that `input()` is buggy. All it's doing is reading a line from `sys.stdin`, there's not much to it.

Comment: Are you using Command-Tab to switch the focus back to the terminal?

Comment: And by the way, there no point to your `.strip()`, since you aren't keeping the input value anyway.

Comment: Do you have multiple Terminal tabs? Are you sure you're selecting the right one when you switch back to Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. This issue I experienced was a Python buffering problem. This is definitely a Python issue and no it's not terminal. In the Python code I have 2 user inputs with a lot of code in-between running multiple processes.

If your script interacts with other processes or subprocesses that use or modify the standard input, the buffering behavior might change unpredictably. This can result in unexpected interactions between different parts of the code that rely on user input. Flushing the user input with `sys.stdin.flush()` can solve this problem.

```
import sys
# Another input and a bunch of code in-between running multiple processes.
while True:
    try:
        sys.stdin.flush()  # Clear input buffer
        input("Press [Enter] key to start distribution...")

        # Rest of the loop code...

    except ValueError as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
```